# Internal Server Error(500) while running load test in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

> I am unable to get response from server so how will correlate dynamic values too

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `500 Internal Server Error` server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

If your test works fine with 1-2 users and you're seeing this HTTP 500 error only when your application is under the load, most probably your application gets overloaded hence fails to provide valid response.

You can already report it as the bug, or if you want you can investigate it a little bit further, to wit:

1. Use [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) and [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond) to see when these errors start occurring (i.e. application works fine till 200 concurrent users and after 201 it starts throwing HTTP 500 errors)
2. Inspect your application logs
3. Make sure that the application has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc, you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) for this
4. Inspect your application middleware configuration and logs (load balancer, application server, database, etc.)
5. Consider collecting [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) and/or [profiler tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) output during the load test execution, this way you will be able to precisely identify the root cause of the problem

Comment: In login page only I am getting this issue for just 1 user